Changing the appearance of a line graph
I have plotted a line graph showing monthly numbers of birds n admitted to a veterinary clinic and how this has changed according to year. However I want the colours of each year to appear more distinctive and the x-axis to start on January.
Attempt
library(ggplot2)
df2 |>
  ggplot(aes(x=month, y=n, group=year, colour=year)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Monthly admission numbers by year") +
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_color_viridis()

Data
df2 = structure(list(year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 
2023L, 2023L, 2023L), month = c("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
"November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", 
"May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", 
"December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", 
"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", 
"February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
"September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", 
"March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December"), n = c(16L, 20L, 31L, 17L, 
18L, 16L, 15L, 32L, 23L, 26L, 7L, 16L, 15L, 20L, 31L, 24L, 16L, 
13L, 9L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 27L, 17L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 
7L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 11L, 37L, 39L, 24L, 22L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 
38L, 21L, 17L, 11L, 27L, 20L, 42L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 7L, 19L, 25L, 
35L, 25L, 9L, 9L, 19L, 53L, 30L, 20L, 22L, 13L, 21L, 44L, 44L, 
28L, 17L, 15L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -72L), groups = structure(list(year = c(2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 
2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 
2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L), month = c("April", 
"August", "December", "February", "January", "July", "June", 
"March", "May", "November", "October", "September", "April", 
"August", "December", "February", "January", "July", "June", 
"March", "May", "November", "October", "September", "April", 
"August", "December", "February", "January", "July", "June", 
"March", "May", "November", "October", "September", "April", 
"August", "December", "February", "January", "July", "June", 
"March", "May", "November", "October", "September", "April", 
"August", "December", "February", "January", "July", "June", 
"March", "May", "November", "October", "September", "April", 
"August", "December", "February", "January", "July", "June", 
"March", "May", "November", "October", "September"), .rows = structure(list(
    4L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 16L, 20L, 
    24L, 14L, 13L, 19L, 18L, 15L, 17L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 28L, 32L, 
    36L, 26L, 25L, 31L, 30L, 27L, 29L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 40L, 44L, 
    48L, 38L, 37L, 43L, 42L, 39L, 41L, 47L, 46L, 45L, 52L, 56L, 
    60L, 50L, 49L, 55L, 54L, 51L, 53L, 59L, 58L, 57L, 64L, 68L, 
    72L, 62L, 61L, 67L, 66L, 63L, 65L, 71L, 70L, 69L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -72L), .drop = TRUE))


Did you search for similiar questions on SO?

Yes I have - I have tried a few ways of changing the colours and order but I haven't been able to make it work.

To fix the order you have to convert to a factor with the desired order, see how do you order Months in ggplot or How do you re-order months in the x-axis for ggplot.

Interesting, as @stefan showed with examples, there are plenty. What serach patterns did you use?

In addition to the solution given for the requested layout, you might also want to try alternative layouts to aid the visual appraisal of your data, e.g. to reveal how monthly admission counts changed over the years:
library(ggridges)

df2 <- ungroup(df2)

yearly_totals <- df2 |> summarise(n = sum(n), .by = year)

df2 |>
  mutate(month = factor(month, levels = month.name[12:1])) |> 
  ggplot(aes(year, month, height = n)) +
  geom_ridgeline(scale = .01, color = NA) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = ~ sprintf('%.0f\n(%.0f)', .x, yearly_totals$n)) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x = '', y = '')

This information can be extracted from your present arrangement, but we are much more used to reading trends from positions (timeline) than from colours.


Oh this is really cool. Thank you. I can see how I could apply this to other data we have too.

You can use the library RColorBrewer, which has a lot of colour palettes.
For example:
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
df2 |>
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(month, levels = month.name),
      y = n, group = as.factor(year), colour = as.factor(year))) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  ggtitle("Monthly admission numbers by year") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y = "Monthly admissions", x = "Month", colour = "Year") +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set2")

Output:

Use RColorBrewer::display.brewer.all() to display all options.
Edit: Added month ordering part. And to reflect a cleaner solution from a comment.

Ah that's great thanks. I had played with RColorBrewer but couldn't get that sort of palette!

Fantastic - that's much simpler than what I was trying to do! Thanks so much.

Note that R already stores the months in a variable called month.name so you don't have to type them all out. factor(month, levels = month.name) will do the trick.
